# Prefer default type parameter in generics over type inference

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

When using generics with default type parameter, i found behavior that i did not expect:

```
function foo<T=string>(arg: T) {}
foo(1); // No error, the function becomes foo(arg: number): void
```

In the above, it seems like there is no point to even have a default value for type parameter.

Another relevant use case:

```
function foo<T=string,U=T[]>(arg1: T, arg2: U) {}
foo("a", 1); // No error, inferred as foo(arg1: string, arg2: number): void
```

This case is especially relevant since I want to enforce that unless user provides parameter U, it must be an array of T.

Basically, for the last use case I wish something like the following behavior:

```
// If both type parameters are specified then the function resolves
// exactly to what's specified:
foo<T, U>(t, u); // becomes foo(t: T, u: U): void

// If only the 1st parameter is specified, then 2nd parameter resolves 
// to T[]:
foo<T>(t, u); // becomes foo(t: T, u: T[]): void

// If no parameters are specified, then the defaults are used:
foo(t, u); // becomes foo(string, string[]): void
```

Is it possible to change the declaration of "foo" somehow to have the behavior above?

Comment: Default type arguments for generic call signatures are only used when inference fails, not merely in the absence of being manually specified.  This is very unlikely to change; if partial inference is ever supported it will be something opted into. (more)

Comment: (continued) I see two questions here: one is "can you enforce the defaults instead of inference" and the answer is "no"; the other is "is it safe to rely on this pattern" and the answer is "very likely" (there's also "is it a valid concern" but that seems to be a rephrasing of your second question).  [Which of those two questions is your primary one](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/511366) and can you [edit] to make that clear?

Comment: I really need answer to both, but looks like you already answered them.  I ll edit the post to leave only one question.

Comment: You're looking for *non-inferential type parameter usage* as described in [ms/TS#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829). This isn't directly implemented in the language but there are ways to emulate it that behave as desired in some use cases; if I pick one of those then your example code [looks like this](https://tsplay.dev/WP8QeW).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll post an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Sure, thanks, it works.  And this pattern is also not likely to break in future versions of the language?  I guess the only thing that having NoInfer as argument types would make the API docs more confusing, but it's fine if there is no other way.

Comment: I don't think `NoInfer<T>` as implemented will break, but someday there might be a *native* way to implement it, at which time you should switch to that.  The API docs are confusing because you're trying to do something TS isn't intended to support; default type arguments aren't used the way you're trying to use them.  I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: I m wondering, if this is not what is intended by TS, what is the pattern to use in this case?  The only one i can think of is having different method names for generic and non-generic cases.

Comment: Aren't we talking about the pattern to use? If I knew of something better than `NoInfer` I would have mentioned it already.  (You could *almost* use overloads but they don't fail in the way we want.) It's not a very common use case as far as I can tell; generic type arguments for function calls are really meant to be *inferred*, not manually specified.  Manual specification of generic type arguments is only done if you don't like what was inferred, not that you don't want inference at all in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [default type arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) in a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signature like `declare function foo<T=string, U=T[]>(⋯): void`, they only act as a fallback for situations where the type arguments cannot be *inferred* by the compiler based on the usages of the type parameter in the call signature.  Default type arguments do not have any effect if the caller does not manually specify the type argument.

This differs from type argument defaults on generic *types* like `type Foo<T=string, U=T[]> {⋯}`. Generic types don't support type argument inference at all; I think [microsoft/TypeScript#32794](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32794) is the relevant open issue asking for that.  For generic types with defaults, if you leave out the argument you get the default.

So you want generic call signatures to behave like generic types. But this isn't a natively supported use case.  In order for this to happen, you'd have to block all generic type argument inference.

---

It turns out that while this use case doesn't seem very common, it does happen that sometimes people want to block a specific type parameter usage from being used for inference (say you have a function like `declare function bar<T>(x: T, y: T): void` and you want `T` to be inferred from `x` but not from `y`).  This is requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829); if there were a `NoInfer<T>` utility type that blocked inference, then you could write `declare function bar<T>(x: T, y: NoInfer<T>): void` to get the desired behavior.

Unfortunately there is no direct support for that feature either. But *fortunately* there are some techniques mentioned in that issue to emulate it, which work for at least some use cases:  one is described [in this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-980401795):

```
type NoInfer<T> = T extends infer S ? S : never;
```

(This uses a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to defer evaluation of the type until after inference occurs.)

And that means you can get what you want if you wrap every single type parameter usage with `NoInfer`:

```
declare function foo<T = string, U = T[]>(
    arg1: NoInfer<T>,
    arg2: NoInfer<U>
): void;
```

And test it out:

```
foo<T, U>(t, u); // okay
foo<T, U>(1, 2); // error
// function foo<T, U>(arg1: T, arg2: U): void

foo<T>(t, [t]); // okay
foo<T>(t, 2); // error
// function foo<T, T[]>(arg1: T, arg2: T[]): void

foo("", [""]); // okay
foo(t, u); // error
foo("", u); // error
// function foo<string, string[]>(arg1: string, arg2: string[]): void
```

That looks good; when you manually specify the type arguments you get them, and when you don't, no inference occurs and the type arguments fall back to the defaults.

---

This approach isn't likely to fail in future versions of TypeScript because there's lots of real world code that would likely break if generic conditional types were evaluated more eagerly.  I could be wrong about that, but at the very least people using `NoInfer` would be unhappy and complain.  More likely is that the feature requested at microsoft/TypeScript#14829 will eventually be natively supported, maybe with a `noinfer` keyword or an intrinsic `NoInfer` utility type, at which point people relying on emulating it should probably change to the native version.  But that's not a backwards compatibility hazard so much as a potential refactoring opportunity.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAehAIAsBdoBwM4C4wHMCW1IFcBGA6AYwHsBbEU9QgJ2IWIDNoQAVATzgFMBlG9OZugQJsnBCACMAFgAcAJgCcwYNA6dwAOWIBJAHYNO1ADwsAfOAC84FuE4APaJ10ATBOHT7D4buAD838CRwXU4AN0MAbmVnTkIAGwBDanUGbF1CaHRiXXAGYmITS3AEaGoPVAAacABVIpYAbQBdUwAKYHAO8CTUCSCtPQNjMwr2zu65Pp1PY2rTYABKINDidGco4A9HagYEwnUbAG9RjoSgkrLdVGAAXw3dLZ29mvAjzvBcIN1sUlxDG+AYvEkuoSLoSuBoEEWFFAYlkuBQeDsEFqus8gUWFVZi1oFVsPMIuAwOBiABrBJsYDokxY1oSKpyAlEiCGWjUUAQVLpTLZXL5Gk1VrdXrWKrjFGLcDLVbKalmHFVerQRpM4lkilU-ny3HgRmE4ms4js4lcjJZHJyqoNZotYVQsXUVATaxNSXS5yy-ItABE3sVvpV+og6sp6IV4HxQds1DZmuIPr9EdVLJjRo5uTSZt51PO5SqucuTSFjpFBcqXUdzrLrqWKw9QA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I m still wondering though if this pattern is ok to use in an API.  It seems in the last comment you mentioned that generic type parameters are meant to be inferred, so is it bad design then?  On the other hand, it seems that there is a request for NoInfer feature and it may become part of the language.  So i m confused then if this is good or bad.

Comment: I wouldn't say "bad design" but I would say "nonstandard approach".  `NoInfer` might be a requested feature but the use cases listed are to block some inference sites, not *all* inference sites. So why do you want people to manually specify type args at all? What about inference is bad? What, specifically, goes wrong if you just allowed people to call `foo(t, u)` where `T` is inferred from `t` and `U` from `u`? Obviously the implementation of `foo()` needs to be able to handle that, and types are erased so there's no actual runtime implications of `T` and `U` being inferred, so... what is it?

Comment: I m not sure, IMO at least specifying arguments manually provides additional type checking.  E.g. if the user has an interface declared somewhere else, e.g. EmplyeeRecord.  Then if they call foo<EmployeeRecord>({...}) then whatever object literal they pass will be typechecked (e.g. in case they made a typo in it or forgot a field), otherwise they will be able to pass anything and get unexpected results at runtime.

Comment: Another reason is to make sure type U gets constrained by type T in some way, unless they specify type U explicitly (in which case I assume they know what they are doing).  In this case it seems the language already supports this constraint as long as type T is specified, I just hope this won't change.

Comment: I suppose in my case, as long as the inference is blocked when the first parameter T is specified, I can live with this, and just assume if no type parameters are specified then anything is allowed.

Comment: the "in which case I assume they know what they are doing" use case is normally covered by type assertions; instead of "`foo<T, U>(t, u)` allows anything", you'd have "`foo(t as string, u as string[])` allows anything (or maybe `t as unknown as string`)". Again, you're coming at this from a nonstandard direction; it would be like *requiring* `let x: string = "abc"` instead of `let x = "abc"`. It's just not a use case TS itself tries to satisfy. Anyway I think I'm repeating myself and don't particularly want to go to a chat room so I'll disengage now. Good luck!

Comment: So you are saying that instead of foo<T, U=T[]>(t: T, u: U); i should have instead: foo<T>(t: T, u: T[]); and if the user needs to pass something different as the second argument then they would do something like foo("abc", myObject as string[]) ?

Comment: I have posted a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76381765/is-it-useful-to-have-this-function-as-generic, which may clarify a little more on what i was asking.