# Is it useful to have this function as generic?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a function that is part of a library's public API, e.g.

```
declare function logObject<T extends Record<string,any>>(obj: T): void;
```

Putting aside implementation, and only looking from the caller's point of view, there are no other dependencies on T in the function signature (in other parameters or return value).  In this case, I could also declare the same function non-generic:

```
declare function logObject(obj: Record<string,any>): void;
```

From the caller's point of view, I could see one reason for using the generic variant.  E.g. if they have

```
interface Person { firstName: string; lastName: string; age: number; ..... }
```

declared somewhere else in the application code, they could use it to check correctness of the value provided to the function.  E.g.

```
import { logObject } from "somewhere";
import { Person } from "somewhere-else";

logObject<Person>({ firstName: "....."; ..... });
```

The above would check the passed value for correctness at compile-time and also flag error if they try to pass some other variable that is not of type Person (or extends Person).  Of course, they can choose to omit the type parameter and it would be inferred.

My question is that if there any advantage of having the API function above as generic (vs non-generic), specifically, whether there are any language guidelines that would apply here, or if it is only a matter of preference.

Comment: I'm wondering how one could answer this question in a way that isn't subjective. My *opinion* is that there's no advantage to use the generic; my thoughts: if `logObject<Person>(person)` guarantees more "correctness" than `logObject(person)`, then surely `logObject<Person, Person>(person)` would be even *more* "correct", since what if the person who wrote `logObject<Person>(person)` made a mistake *both* times? If you actually want a function that only accepts a person for reuse then you can make one (`const logPerson: (p: Person)=>void = logObject`) without unmotivated generics. (more...)

Comment: (...continued) But this is all opinion, I don't know of any "authoritative source" for such things.  How can we proceed here?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I guess you gave me the answer.  Although I m not sure how logObject<Person,Person> would be any different from logObject<Person> as far as value correctness.  I m not sure if you want to post the asnwer, or should I delete the question?

Comment: It isn't any more correct, but neither is `logObject<Person>(person)` any more correct than `logObject(person)`: it's just more redundant. If you are launching nuclear weapons you should make sure to [turn two keys](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-man_rule) instead of one, but even if `logObject()` were that critical, it's still one person turning both keys. It's not like one developer writes `log<Person>` in one place and another one writes `(person)` in another; it's the same place. It's just repetition, not safety. Something like `logPerson` above would at least allow separation.

Comment: But again, this is opinion and other people can differ. I don't have a source outside my own head for my answer, so it doesn't belong here.  You might keep the question open if you can imagine someone providing something like an objectively correct answer, but I can't really do so.  It's up to you, though.  Good luck!

Comment: It's not meant to protect against intentional misuse, only unintentional errors. E.g. if we have something like function logObject<T>(obj: Expand<T>): void; then the developer typing logObject<Person>() in VSCode would be able to see the properties they need to enter.  But I agree that the small benefit is not worth the complexity.